Fix MacOS partition after resize
I have a Macbook Pro 2015 where I have Linux in dual-boot. The Linux installation was running out of space, so I decided to shrink the OSX partition. Unfortunately, after resizing using the OSX Disk Utility, the GPT partition got ruined. This is how it looks like right now:


I followed the following questions to resolve my problem:

Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
MacOS partition showing as "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFF"

I understood that I have to use the gpt command to remove and add the problematic partition. I am unsure of what the correct GUID key should be. I was using the Mac OS Extended (Journaled) filesystem on this.
How do I proceed?
